# How to deal with a question where the "notable claim" turned out to be invalid?

Tags: discussion

Recently, [this](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45162/are-the-democrats-handing-out-legitimate-subpoenas-to-the-trump-organization) question was asked and answered.  The original version of the question did not have the source of the notable claim provided.  When pressed, OP provided a link to a hour-long podcast with no timestamp as to when the claim was made.

This was accepted at face-value (admittedly a fault of my own) and was answered using the assumption that the claim was made at some point in the podcast.

Upon being pressed by a user to look more into the context, I went back and listened to the podcast, only to find out that ***the claim was never made by the notable source in the video***.

The question is currently on hold for being off-topic.  Should the question be closed?  Deleted?  Left up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest we go back to first principles here to work out the best action.

There are several reasons for demanding notability references:

- To ensure the claim is widely believed, so we spend our time wisely. If an answer has already been posted and accepted, then this is kind of moot.
- To ensure the claim is being accurately represented. Sometimes people simply misunderstand claims or don't realise it was satirical/fictional. In such cases, we can choose to close the question (because no-one else believes the claim) or provide an answer to explain the confusion (if it is widely believed).
- As a starting point for context to understand the claim - e.g. what definitions might the claimant have been using, etc. If an answer is possible without this, there is no need.

Comment: Right, I made the mistake of assuming the link to the podcast included the statement made.  In hindsight, I should have asked for a timestamp in the video, as that would have solved this issue before going after a claim that was never made in the first place.  I know in the past if we're asked to examine a claim made in a video we would ask for a timestamp but it slipped my mind.  I'm guessing the question should remain closed, but not deleted then?